# Rails Action_Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using admin mailer in my Rails 4 app.

I have two emails to send out upon registration. One is to me and the other is to the user. They are supposed to send from different email addresses, each of which is specified in the from field in the mailer method (as set out below).  The problem is they are both being sent from the email address specified as the sender in the first method.

My mailer methods are:

```
def new_user_waiting_for_approval(user)
    @user = user
    mail(to: "aa@gmail.com", from: "bb@gmail.com", 
    subject: "Registration Request #{user.first_name} #{user.last_name} <#{user.email}>")
  end

  def new_user_waiting_for_access(user)
    @user = user
    mail(to: user.email, from: "cc@gmail.com", subject: "Welcome, #{user.first_name}")
  end
```

Inside my Admin_Mailer class, I have a default 'from:' email address above the method which is specified as the sender in the first of the above methods. This might be overriding the from specified in the method itself.

Does anyone know how to specify different senders in separate methods so that my emails send from the appropriate email address?

Thank you

Comment: It's [ActionMailer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) and not `Admin_Mailer`.  Your config looks good; When a `from:` attribute is specified as part of the arguments for the `mail` method, it is used and not the one provided as `default :from`. Could you reverify that the mail is coming from the wrong email address? Also, do you have tests to verify the functionality of the mailer? If not best to go over http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#mailer-testing and add tests to confirm the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you couldn't figure it out by changing the configs you can use the code given below.

Add this code snippet to your code base.

```
class Emailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def activation_instructions(recipients_emails, sender = nil, mail_subject = nil, text = "")
    subject       mail_subject || "Default subject"
    recipients    recipients_emails
    from          sender || "default_mail_id@abc.com"
    sent_on       Time.now
    content_type  "text/html"
    body          text
  end
end
```

And you can send the mail by calling the above defined method as follows.

```
Emailer.deliver_activation_instructions("recient@abc.com", "sender@abc.com", "Subject", "content")
```